# How to have a variable in Kotlin to accept any subclass of given class

Tags: kotlin

I want this

```
data class ActivityInfo(title: String, activity: Activity::class.java)
```

That I can hopefully use with subclasses of Activity

```
val mainActivityInfo= ActivityInfo("main activity",MainActivity::class.java) //where MainActivity extends Activity
```

How do I do this in kotlin

Comment: `activityClass: Class<out Activity>`

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
import android.app.Activity

data class ActivityInfo(val title: String, val activity: Class<out Activity>)

class YourActivity : Activity()
```

**Usage**

```kotlin
ActivityInfo("name", YourActivity::class.java)
```